# remove text after two spaces in a java string

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove the string after two or more consecutive spaces. I have tried:

```
String.replaceAll(".+$.+$","");
```

But its not working. I need something like below:

```
String = "hi there  how are you?" 

output:
String = "hi there".
```

Please suggest a simple regex for the above.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `str = str.replaceFirst("\\s{2,}.*$", "");`

Comment: @anubhava thanks a lot for the quick response.Its perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage non-greediness with a positive lookahead to make sure the matched portion is followed by two or more whitespaces:

```
^.*?(?=\\s{2,})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w6Y3au/1)

Answer (score 1):

All the other methods will include `\r`, `\n`, `\t`, `\f` or `\v`. Which i don't think you want since you just want `2 spaces`. Easier to use `substring` in this case.

```
    String a = "hi there  how are you?"; 
    if (a.indexOf("  ") > 0) a = a.substring(0, a.indexOf("  "));
    System.out.println(a);
```

**Output:** hi there

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to answer.

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceFirst(" {2,}.*$", ""); // only space
```

Or:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("\\s{2,}.*$", ""); // all whitespaces
```